# Azure Application Insights - specific datacenter - deriving correct firewall configuration

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

A server behind a firewall needs to send telemetrics to a specific Azure data center (Application Insights) and I need to open the right IP addresses + port numbers in a firewall.

The documentation from Microsoft is very confusing here: If I look at the IP-range json from Microsoft (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=56519) there are a lot of IP address intervals without specifying which data center they are relevant for.

I assume I need to consider these two system services: ApplicationInsightsAvailability + AzureMonitor. But how do I identify the ones that are relevant for my data center?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ip-addresses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Azure Datacenter IP ranges** (XML files) was deprecated in June 30, 2020.
So Please start using the **JSON** files listed below. IP Ranges for each cloud, broken down by **region** and by the tagged services in that cloud are now available on MS Download:

- Public
  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519
- US Gov
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57063
- Germany
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57064
- China
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57062

These JSON files are updated weekly and include versioning both for the full file and each individual service tag in that file.

You can **filter** out the **IP address** using **Region**
[image]

So that you can use the [Service Tag Discovery API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/service-tags-overview#service-tags-on-premises) to integrate with an on-premises firewall.

By programmatically retrieving the information using **Service Tag Discovery API**

```
$serviceTags = Get-AzNetworkServiceTag -Location eastus2
$storage = $serviceTags.Values | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Storage" }
$storage.Properties.AddressPrefixes
```

We have another way to retrieve the current list of service tags together with the IP address range

- [REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/servicetags/list)
- [Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/Get-AzNetworkServiceTag)
- [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network#az-network-list-service-tags)

Refer [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653) for more information.